# ORA-04091 - How can I alter a table that a trigger fires on?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, ora-04091

So I have table `foo` and I would like to delete other `foo` rows when trigger `t_foo` fires:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "t_foo" AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON foo

/*delete some other records from foo that are not :NEW.* or :OLD.* \*
```

How would I go about doing this without getting a `ORA-04091:` table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it. Is this even possible?

Comment: You want to alter the structure of the table in a trigger? Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant alter foo rows, not the structure...I'll edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not do this in a stored procedure, where you can wrap the insert and deletes in a transaction, and can clearly document this side-effect behavior?

Comment: So you're saying put the delete logic in a stored procedure and call it from this trigger?

Comment: No. Call the SP directly, to insert the row and do the side-effect deletes, wrapped in a transaction. The SP+transaction approach avoids the mess of mutating tables and is more self-documenting.

Answer (score 6):

See [Tom Kyte's definitive article on this topic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-jul/o43asktom-1958803.html).

Comment: FYI - This link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

This basically implies you have interdependent rows in your table, possibly a hierarchical structure with a self-reference from a column to the primary key. Did you think about `ON DELETE CASCADE`?