# Trigger which will change other table on update

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

My goal is to create trigger, which will update the value in `Project` in case of `Task` update. Every task has an estimated time, project has column where the average estimated time is stored. What I want is that if the estimated time of one task is updated, the trigger will change average time of project.

I can't figure out how to do this, I have come up with code below, but it is not working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_task_update
AFTER update
ON Task
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE Project p SET (avg_task_estimated_time) = (SELECT AVG(estimatedTime) FROM TASK t WHERE t.project_idProject= p.idProject) WHERE p.idProject = :NEW.project_idProject;
END;
/
```

After update on table `TASK` I am getting the error:

```
ORA-04091: table TASK is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

Comment: Can you post the error? Some sample data and your table structure may help also.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query the table which triggers the code (at row level trigger). Workaround example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805986/oracle-after-delete-trigger-how-to-avoid-mutating-table-ora-04091](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806193/465201)